# Need to Redirect on custom page After Click on Add to Cart - Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

We need to display one custom page after customer click on add to cart from product page. if customer can click on skip than its redirect to cart page other wise stay on custom page.

We can display some static products on custom page where customer can bought product from there.

Please let me know if any one know this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please override your cart controller and update function of _goBack(). you can add your custom URL instead of

```
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
```

I have also share you how we can override cart controller. Please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267425/how-to-override-cart-controller-coupon-action-in-our-custom-module-magento/20272173#20272173)